# PHP Image upload Filecheck Issue

Tags: php, upload, image

I have PHP form where a user can upload an image. I check this form for several other problems like empty fields and every problem gets their own error message. If there is more than one error, de form doesn't send the data and the user sees an error message. So far, so good! Now I want to show an error message when the image isn't a PNG, JPG or GIF or is larger than 250k. I've written a code, that doesn't seem to do anything! I can leave the entire form blank and set a .MP3 as 'file to upload', all the error messages appear, excep the one for the image. What's going wrong? Here is my code:

```
$aErrors = array();

$filecheck = basename($_FILES['bedrijfslogo']['name']);
$ext = strtolower(substr($filecheck, strrpos($filecheck, '.') + 1));

if (!(($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "gif" && $ext != "png") || ($_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["type"] != "image/jpeg" && $_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["type"] != "image/gif" && $_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["type"] != "image/png") ||    ($_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["size"] > 250000))){

    $aErrors['bedrijfslogo'] = 'Uw bedrijfslogo is te groot of niet het juiste formaat';
  }
```

And the code inside the HTMl form :

```
<tr>
<td class="first">Bedrijfslogo:</td>
<td><input tabindex="8" type="file" name="bedrijfslogo" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['bedrijfslogo'])?$_POST['bedrijfslogo']:""; ?>" class="wizardinput" style="background-color:white;"></td>
</tr>
```

What's going wrong guys? Big thanks in advance!

Comment: You can post the complete form?

Comment: confused, although I'm making an assumption but given your form field name but shouldn't it be `&& $_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["size"] > 250000` your logic checks if it's an images or if it's less than a certain size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is a little confusing

```
if (!(($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "gif" && $ext != "png") || ($_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["type"] != "image/jpeg" && $_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["type"] != "image/gif" && $_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["type"] != "image/png") ||    ($_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["size"] > 250000))){
    $aErrors['bedrijfslogo'] = 'Uw bedrijfslogo is te groot of niet het juiste formaat';
}
```

Try simplifying it

```
if (!preg_match("/^jpg|gif|png$/", $ext) || !preg_match("/^image\/(jpeg|gif)$/", $_files["bedrijfslogo"]["type"]) || $_FILES["bedrijfslogo"]["size"] > 250000) {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot simpeler indeed. However, using your code, I always get the error message, also when I don't select any file to upload?

Comment: @user1555076 Remove the parentheses from jpg|gif|png. Edited for correctness.

Comment: @user1555076 Just out of curiosity, what language is that? Something Nordic?

Comment: Just tried the corrected code, still displaying the error message all the time. Including when I don't select anything to upload. I must say, your code looks fine to me? Then again, I also thought my code would do the trick! The language you see is 'Dutch', I'm from Holland! Hope you have a solution, thanks.

Comment: @user1555076 I would check each individual logic comparison and see which one is returning an improper true/false value. My regular expressions may not be 100% accurate - I tested them briefly before putting them in the answer, but not extensively. BTW I'm 1/8 Dutch (American). Nice to meet a true Hollander!

Comment: Okay, I broke it down to only checking the file size, however, no result, same as my own code earlier. I really dont see it: 
if (($_FILES['bedrijfslogo']['size']) > 250) {

    $aErrors['bedrijfslogo'] = 'Uw bedrijfslogo is te groot of niet het juiste formaat';
  }

Plain and simple right? Everything I upload is bigger than 250 bytes! Though: no error message.

Comment: @user1555076 Do a var_dump on $_FILES and verify the file size.

Comment: I'm gonna call it a night, I simply don't see it. The var dump turned up empty, is that even possible?

if ($_FILES['bedrijfslogo']['size'] > 250) {
 $aErrors['bedrijfslogo'] = 'Logo te groot!';
  }


My input field:

<tr>
<td class="first">Bedrijfslogo:</td>
<td><input tabindex="8" type="file" id="bedrijfslogo" name="bedrijfslogo" class="wizardinput" style="background-color:white;"></td>
</tr>

What am I missing here that´s driving me insane?

Comment: @user1555076 What's your enctype in the form? Please tell me it's multipart/form-data

Comment: YOU SIR!... are my own American Hero! That was the problem the entire time!! I can't believe I forgot to add that to my form!! Thanks for all your help Matt, I'm really grateful!

Comment: I just got really excited to know that I helped! Good luck in the future, kind sir!